# Visual Studio Code - Apply quick fix to all files in folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, automation, scripting, command, action

We are migrating from JavaScript to TypeScript.
In vscode I use quick fixes "Add all missing members", "Infer all types from usage".
Furthermore, I use a plugin called TsAutoReturnType and its command "TsAutoReturnType: File".
This declares the fields of a class, adds types to parameters, and adds return types to functions / methods.

Now, I would like to call these commands on each file in a folder.

- Is it possible to script or compose vscode commands using built-in features?
- Is it possible to apply commands to multiple files at once or all files in a folder (recursively)?
- Is there a command line interface for vscode to call its commands from a script?